# How to set multiple markers based on PHP variables?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using Google Maps JavaScript API v3, I have a map where I can position a marker based on LatLng.

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(), southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random()),
```

[image]

What I want to do is place a marker on a City based on a PHP variable E.G

```
$town_1 = "London";
$town_2 = "Reading";
```

And my desired result would be two markers, on their town respectively.

Which theoretically could look something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: <?php echo $town_1; ?>
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Town ' + i
                });
```

But my map disappears which isn't very desirable at all

**How does one place multiple markers on embedded Google Maps per a city (Not Lat/Long)?**

Answer (score 2):

You can try to geocode the city using this script slightly modified from documentation of Google Map Api v3:

```
function codeAddress() {
   var address = <?php echo $town_1; ?>
   geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: results[0].geometry.location
  });
} else {
  alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
}
```

});
}

The documentation is available here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

Geocode could be a slow operation: normally, if is possible, I save on database the coordinate of the address, where will be set the marker.